# Processing loop restricted by a connection pool (?)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm looking for some strategic help here, since I am new to TPL.

### Situation

I have an application that coordinates data between 2 disparate LOB systems, ones that do not talk to each other. So, it looks a bit like:

```
[ System 1 ] < ----- [ App ] ----- > [ System 2 ]
```

During its processing, the app performs the following tasks:

1. App creates a connection to System 1. This connection must screen-scrape a web application, so it uses a  and System 2, verifying each one is available.
2. App requests list of IDs from System A.
3. This list is run through, item by item. Processing that list:

   1. App requests data from System 1. This system does not provide any service interface, so the app uses a WebRequest to both GET and POST requests to System 1. In addition to web page data scraped, a file may also be downloaded.
   2. With data from System 1, App submits data to System 2 via several web service calls. Several calls may be made, and a file may be uploaded.

There are often tens of thousands of items in the loop. There is no dependency between these items, so they seem to be a good candidate for `Task`-based processing.

However, at most, there can be about 20 connections to System 1 and about 10 connections to System 2. So, the simple idea of just creating and destroying sessions for each item in the loop (like you might do in a simple `Parallel.ForEach Task`) would be *prohibitively costly*. Rather, I want to **share** the connections, in effect, creating a *connection pool* of sorts. That pool would be created before the tasks started up. When each `Task` starts its work, it would basically wait until it could get a connection from the pool. Once the task is complete, the connection would be released, and another `Task` could get ahold of it. In this case, the Scheduler limit is not just the CPUs; it's also the **maximum number** of connections to System 2.

### Desire

I'm looking for the approach. I don't mind doing the work to figure out the implementation, but I need the best strategic approach.

*How do I get the task loop to work with a limited number of these connections*? Or do I have to go back to the old style of Thread allocation, and just manually pass the freed up connections as the threads complete their tasks? Some kind of mutex array? If so, how will the Tasks grab an open connection? Some type of concurrent bag or am I just going the wrong way?

Any help would be ***greatly*** appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "connections" and "sessions"? HTTP calls (therefore Web service calls) are stateless by definition. Are you referring to authentication costs or are your systems performing some special housekeeping for repeated calls?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the terms interchangeably. Yes, the web service call is stateless, but the service uses authentication headers. That header includes an authentication token from an initial authorization call. If the token is not included, then the call is refused. The process of generating a token is costly. So, I really should have written the creation of the token instead of a session. However, the concept is the same. Eventually, the token will time out, and another one must be retrieved. I do keep some structures around as helpers for the token-based session, but nothing major.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) for each connection pool will work well. If a thread attempts to get a connection from an empty pool, that thread will be blocked until another thread returns a connection to the pool.

You should also set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to the size of the bigger pool, to make sure there aren't unnecessarily many threads, most of them waiting to get a connection from the pool.

With that, your code could look like this:

```
var connection = serviceAConnections.Take();

// use the connection

serviceAConnections.Add(connection);
```

But a better approach might be to add a level of abstraction over that:

```
using (var connectionHolder = serviceAConnections.Get())
{
   var connection = connectionHolder.Connection;

   // use the connection
}
```

Comment: That approach looks interesting. The blocking collection could hold the pool. Then, when each task starts, it attempts to get a connection from the collection. If it cannot get one, then it will wait a period of time (randomized within a range) to try again. Finally, once it gets the connection from the collection, the task continues to completion.

Comment: More thoughts...is the Task blocked? Or does it just poll periodically? What then determines which one gets a freed connection in the collection...the blocking collection's queue mechanism? I'll do more readying, but thanks for the direction.

Comment: @TizzyD I don't see the need for the randomization. If it cannot get one, it will wait until there is one. That's what `Take()` does (and why the collection is called “blocking”).

Comment: Looking at the blocking collection has been very helpful. There are two approaches I'm considering: one using the connections as elements going in and out of the blocking collection with a set of Tasks that consume the connections, and one using the connections as Tasks that consume the data in the blocked collection. I favor the latter, although I might try both to see which is better.

Comment: I was holding out until I did my verifications. I also had to travel 5 hours last night. However, I accept the answer. And...very much, a big thank you!